# How to rig an election?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

In my game as the king of Ireland/Wales/Castille, my dear neighbour the king of Scotland, for some crazy reason, agreed to have his brother, who is eligible to the throne, marry my sister in a matrilineal marriage.

The kingdom of Scotland has an elective succession law, and it consists of five duchies. The king himself owns a single duchy, but there's another guy owning three! The last remaining duke is married to some girl of my dynasty. On top of that, one of the earls is in my dynasty. I don't know if the last two things really matter in the equation, but they seem to like me well enough.

Now, I do know I won't get to control Scotland personally, but it's better to have my friend do it, than some Scottish chump.

**So how do I rig this election?**
I'm thinking of showering my new favourite brother-in-law with fancy titles, to make him a more attractive choice.
Or could I try to bribe the superduke? Would that even influence his choice?

**Is it even possible to rig an election in a different realm?**

Comment: I don't think you can—I'm pretty sure the superduke will soon be the new King of Scotland. But you'll have a claim in your dynasty you can press in war to put your nephew on the throne, which will eventually mean you'll have (appropriately distant) kin you can marry to get *yourself* (er, future self) a claim on the throne that you can press personally. (In fact, this is what just happened in my Irish game. British Empire, here I come!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a couple of options, none of which are ideal or guarantee success.

- The most straightforward is to simply continue murdering the heirs until an heir of your choosing appears as the top choice in the election screen.
- Another way is to gain an electoral title in Scotland. Look at their de jure counties and try to snatch one in a war. Once you've done that you can nominate a candidate for the Scottish throne as well as see their second and third options for the heir, which can help with the murdering option I mentioned above
- Thirdly, if you are up for a major war, see if the brother you talk about has a heritable claim to the throne (weak or strong). Strong heritable claims are great as the children will be of your dynasty (matrilineal marriage) and have the claim. If you can't get them elected you can go ahead and press their claim. T

A nice addition to this is if you make your own kingdom also elective and then nominate the new king of Scotland (now of your dynasty if the above succeeded) as your heir. You can then join the two kingdoms together.

Comment: Good points all around. I had never thought to merge the two kingdoms by changing my own succession law. It might prove difficult in my own case as I rule three kingdoms, but have low demesne limit – so getting my chosen guy elected in four kingdoms might be a challenge. However, still a great idea!

Comment: Yeah, having multiple kingdom titles can be a pain under elective, as your favourite candidate might not be eligible in one of the kingdoms. I tend to choose elective in my games though (for the quality successors you can pick) and so try to destroy all the newly acquired kingdom titles as soon as I have a good standing with my vassals. Although you usually get quite a hefty opinion penalty modifier with the de jure vassals, you also loose the negative points due to "desires kingdom of ___", so the penalty is not as large as it seems.

Answer (score -1):

A fast way to tip the election scales in your favor is to bribe all your vassals. Thats what i did to retain control over scotland. If that fails, Assassins galore!

Comment: Yes, but that would only work if I ruled in Scotland, which I do not. It's completely separate domain, but I would like to rig the election – which, as far as I understand, is not possible unless I want to kill every other eligible heir.

Comment: Ah I misunderstood then. Gaining control is admittedly quite different than keeping it.